# Passing information to renderer

Tags: android, multithreading, libgdx

In my `libgdx` app I have a `renderer`:

```
@Override
public void render() {
   if (mUpdate) {
      update();
   }
   .
   .
   .    
}
```

The `update` call changes arrays which holds object that are used in subsequent calls in `render`.

My app disables continous rendering in `create`:

```
Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
```

Each time I want the `update` call to fire I set `mUpdate = true` from a UI thread (fired of by user action) and request rendering:

```
public void invalidate(boolean update) {
    mUpdate = update;
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
}
```

Now the problem is `invalidate(false)` might be called in between implicitly by a non user action which in turn might set `mUpdate = false`. This leads to `update` never being called (but we will have 2 x `requestRendering`).

What would be my best solution here? Should I have an `AtomicInteger` counter to be sure `update` is always being called in my `render` call?

```
public void invalidate(boolean update) {
    if (update) {
        mUpdateCounter.getAndIncrement();
    }
    Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();
}
```

and then

```
@Override
public void render() {
    if (mUpdateCounter.get() > 0) {
        update();
        mUpdateCounter.getAndDecrement();
    }
    .
    .
    .
}
```

Or if it would be possible to pass instance information (`mUpdate`) per `renderer` call.

Comment: I don't understand why you need mUpdate. Do you ever call `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();` without want to call `update()`? The `render()` method will not be called without `Gdx.graphics.requestRendering();` so why you need mUpdate to prevent `update()`?

Comment: update() is a slow call and it manipulates some data structures (which I need to do in the render call). But I don't want to do it everytime as it isn't needed for some object animation (translation). I do call render and set mUpdate = false sometimes yes.

Comment: You can call update directly in your `invalidate(boolean)` method : `if(update) update()`. When you need the render thread use `Gdx.app.postRunnable()`

Comment: Gdx.app.postRunnable() sounds like a good solution. I'll try it out.

Comment: Morchul answer my question with your last answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call update directly in your `invalidate(boolean)` method:

```
if (update)
    update();
```

If you need the render thread you can use `Gdx.app.postRunnable()`:

```
if (update) {
    Gdx.app.postRunnable(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            update();
        }
    });
}
```